# When will the largest eigenvector have only non-zero elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\boldsymbol{R}$ be a positive semi definite Hermitian matrix (with rank at least 2). Let $\lambda \neq 0$ be its largest eigenvalue and $\boldsymbol{x}$ its associated eigenvector. Is there a restriction on the elements of $\boldsymbol{R}$ that would ensure that every element $x_k$ of $\boldsymbol{x}$ is non-zero? This question comes from radio astronomy, if you try to calibrate visibilities you estimate your gain solutions (the $\boldsymbol{x}$), which can never have zero entries [unless your telescope is off], I am trying to find the mathematical restriction this imposes on your visibility matrix $\boldsymbol{R}$? Any ideas please... I have hid a dead end...

Answer (score 1):

One sufficient condition comes from the Perron-Frobenius theorem: if some positive integer power ${\bf R}^m$ has all its matrix elements strictly positive, then $\bf R$'s largest eigenvalue (in absolute value) $\lambda$ is simple, $\lambda^m > 0$, and it has an eigenvector
with strictly positive elements.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, what is the complex extension of this theorem (I hope there is one)? The matrix $\boldsymbol{R}$ is complex (Hermitian). Again thanx for the reply.

Comment: The complex extension states that if $\mathcal{R}\{{\boldsymbol{R}^k}\}>0$ $\forall k \geq k_0\in\mathbb{N}$ and $|\lambda_1|$ is the largest absolute eigenvalue then its associated eigenvector $\boldsymbol{x}$ satisfies $\mathcal{R}\{\boldsymbol{x}\}>0$. This is an extremly strong condition isnt there a simpler one?